# Unable to concatenate tokens in CPP

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

(Yes, it's the dreaded C preprocessor concatenation of tokens again...)

I am trying to craft a CPP macro that takes a number of parts of a formula and feeds them in to make the finished product. I have tried `##` in various ways but always run up against the dreaded "pasting X and Y does not give a valid preprocessor token" problem.

I have the tokens `23`, `TRIS` and `SET` and need to make the macro expand to:

```
(sfr_t)(&TRISASET + ((23 / 16) * 0x100))
```

That is, something along the lines of:

```
#define gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB(P, R, S)  (sfr_t)(& ## R ## A ## S ## + (((P)/16) * 0x100))
                                            &    TRIS A    SET      (23)
```

But of course that doesn't work.

I've tried taking each portion and feeding them to another macro to do the concatenation, but it does just the same.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You want `gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB(23, TRIS, SET)` to result in `(sfr_t)(&TRISASET + ((23 / 16) * 0x100))`? How should `gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB` be used? How do you call `gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB`? Replace the `S ## +` to `S +`

Comment: @KamilCuk `gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB` will be used like a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&TRIS` and `SET+` are not valid preprocessor tokens. You can only join with `##` tokens that will result in valid preprocessor tokens.  Just don't - they are separate tokens anyway.

```
#define gpioPIN_TO_REGSUB(P, R, S)  (sfr_t)(&R ## A ## S + (((P)/16) * 0x100))
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Yes, that's looking better. I was getting confused and concatenating when I didn't need to concatenat.

Comment: @majenko: yes. The problem isn't that token concatenation is dreaded. It's that it is overloved. Better to dread it. Only use when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @rici Yeah. In this case it's either use token concatenation or write a script to churn out hundreds of near identical lines of code for me.

Comment: `&` is a valid preprocessor token *by itself*, but `&TRIS` is not. Similarly with `+` and `SET+`. But you *could* use `##` to paste together a `&` and a `=` to make `&=`.